# Spark - SQL Joins Does all Combinations Get Created?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This question is for Spark but I assume (?) it may be more general to any SQL table join.

Lets say we have table A and B. Then we issue this command:

```
select a.* from a inner join b on a.col1 - b.col1 <= 0.5
```

Behind the scenes, is first a cartesian product created and then filtered based on the criteria of a.col1 - b.col1 <= 0.5 OR is each and every combination of rows between the tables evaluated and then if the criteria returns TRUE, the resulting row returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Join conditions, which are not based on equality of values (results of user defined function calls, values computed on columns from different tables, and non-equality compare operators) cannot be optimized and are evaluated as Cartesian product followed by selections.

It is pretty easy to confirm that if you check resulting execution plans. For example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.range(1000).select(rand() as "col1").createOrReplaceTempView("a")
spark.range(1000).select(rand() as "col1").createOrReplaceTempView("b")

spark.sql("select a.* from a inner join b on a.col1 - b.col1 <= 0.5").explain
// == Physical Plan ==
// *Project [col1#9]
// +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Inner, ((col1#9 - col1#16) <= 0.5)
//    :- *Project [rand(3279117551830311353) AS col1#9]
//    :  +- *Range (0, 1000, step=1, splits=4)
//    +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
//       +- *Project [rand(-3185472069145487350) AS col1#16]
//          +- *Range (0, 1000, step=1, splits=4)
```

and similarly if you disable broadcast joins:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)

spark.sql("select a.* from a inner join b on a.col1 - b.col1 <= 0.5").explain
// == Physical Plan ==
// *Project [col1#9]
// +- CartesianProduct ((col1#9 - col1#16) <= 0.5)
//    :- *Project [rand(3279117551830311353) AS col1#9]
//    :  +- *Range (0, 1000, step=1, splits=4)
//    +- *Project [rand(-3185472069145487350) AS col1#16]
//       +- *Range (0, 1000, step=1, splits=4)
```

Comment: So if the join criteria was b.col1 == b.col1 then no cartesian product is created and the join is optimized? As is above, the result is the same really as doing 2 steps - cartesian product followed by filter?

Comment: Yes, equality joins can be optimized. And the answer for the second question is positive - please checked attached execution plans.

Comment: I am reading that turning off broadcast joins is the best thing to do with this sort of query.

Comment: Depending on the size of data it might improve or decrease actual performance, but in the big picture it is still O(N^2) no matter which option you choose.